# How to determine the process that currently using a specific DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I met a problem when building with Visual studio, it says one DLL　is　not accessible because it is currently used by another process, my question is how can I determine the "another process"?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? :)

Comment: Maybe that's worth a try :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has a facility that allows you to search through the currently running processes for a specific file. To perform this search go to `Find`->`Find Handle or DLL...` and then enter the name of the file you are interested in.

Answer (score 12):

tasklist /m thelocked.dll

Suggested by

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winclient/2004/07/08/how-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-dll/

Comment: returned `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.` on the DLL in use, while the [ProcessExplorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600897/4669135) solution worked

Comment: This is more safe and should be used instead of third-party apps

Answer (score 2):

While *Process Explorer* is the best tool in general, what this error *usually* means when VS throws it at you is that **the application you're trying to compile** is still running (from an earlier run) and therefore the linker can't write its output.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may use "close handle" feature inside [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the Find function (Find -> Find Handle or DLL) from [SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). Helped me quite a few times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what processes have loaded which Dll's.

Comment: Since this is a programming site and not helpdesk, I suspect that the OP is interested in the APIs that this Process Explorer is using, rather than the tool itself.

Comment: Well 4 other people have posted PE as a solution, so we will soon see if this is what the OP is after.